# Available space not changing when resizing a partition

Tags: partition, gparted

In my computer I have several partitions. I have one partition with Fedora that had just below 40 GB of space, and which I wanted to make bigger. Therefore, using GParted, I moved 10 GB from another partition to the Fedora partition. Now, according to GParted, I should have just below 50 GB (see `sda12`):

[image]

However, from Fedora itself the available space looks different:

[image]

This was the same space that was available before I resized the partition. How do I make that space actually available to Fedora?

Comment: Is this a `root` partition of your Fedora?

Comment: @user1700494 I'm not sure what that means nor how I can find that out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've enlarged the partition on disk, but there is a stack of containers which need to be told about the change before you can use it.

First, you need to tell LVM (the logical volume manager) to use the extra space (`gparted` may have done this already, but this step won't hurt if done multiple times):

```
pvresize /dev/sda12
```

You should now see extra free space when you run

```
vgs
```

to list the available volume groups (one of which will be using `/dev/sda12`). You can now add space to the `/` partition; this involves resizing the logical volume itself, then the contained filesystem. `lvextend` is used to perform the first step, and it can delegate the second to `fsadm` itself, so one command should do the trick:

```
lvextend -r -L+10G fedora/root
```

Now your root filesystem should show 10GB more free space!

Comment: Step 1 worked, however step 2 gives me only one volume group. The output of vgs is
  `VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree 

  fedora   1   2   0 wz--n- 49.24g 10.79g`
and I see no root logical volume. The fsdam command predicatbly gives a wrong argument error

Comment: The `vgs` output is correct, it lists 10.79GB free space. To see the logical volumes, you need to run `lvs`. The `fsadm` command needs to be adapted to suit the names of your volume groups and logical volumes...

Comment: ... except that I'd got the `fsadm` command wrong, I'd forgotten the `resize` argument!

Comment: thanks now I see the root volume. However, if I try to resize to, say 45G (or anything above 35 G), I get the error that I do not have enough space:  `The containing partition (or device) is only 9098240 (4k) blocks.
You requested a new size of 11796480 blocks.`

Comment: Sorry about that, I got `fsadm`'s role mixed up with `lvextend`'s — or rather, I though `fsadm` could drive `lvextend`, but it's the other way around.

Comment: Step2 worked like a charm !!